# Wordpress changing site URL with WWW give problems

Tags: wordpress, web

In wordpress admin panel, settings/general, 
I changed the "site URL"  from   site.com   to **www**.example.com

so now I have:

WordPress Address (URL) : http://example.com

Site Address (URL): http://www.example.com

(Wordpress in installed on root)

**But I have problems**
because it's clear that paths are not correctly read from code: 
site is visible but
but icons fonts is not visible
admin have problems and so on...

I asked to disable **openbase_dir option**  to my provider  Nothing changed
I tryed to add

**RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$**

but not all was fixed...

Anyone could help me please? 
thank you !!!

.HTACCESS

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
```

Comment: Moving a WordPress installation is documented here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress (yes, changing site.com to www.site.com is a move).

Comment: yes I read all and tryid all but it's not working ....it's the second time (2 blogs) that I need to change it but the wordpress guide it's not working everytime you need to make some fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours and many settings, I discover that if you want to change your wordpress blog from

**not-www** to **www**

you need ONLY to change in settings page / generale 
both the fieds, not only 1!!!

So in this way:

from:

WordPress Address (URL) : http://example.com

Site Address (URL): http://example.com

to

WordPress Address (URL) : http://**www**.example.com

Site Address (URL): http://**www**.example.com

that's all!

ATTENZION: Do not touch the 1° field (Wordpress address) if you want to change the directory and read the wordpress guide!

Answer (score 0):

in your theme don't use static URLs at all, always use `the_permalink()` for posts, and use `bloginfo( 'template_url' );` for style sheet and javascript references.

for me I never change the URL from admin panel, I always export the DataBase into .sql file when I'm done development, then open this .sql file with notepad++ and replace all 'localhost/wpexamplesite' occurrences with 'www.mywebsite.com'.

I have been doing this for many years, and it works every time.

one more thing, if your server is in the same local network as your pc, then try changing your DNS to google's 8.8.8.8, sometimes the system admins in office networks make the mistake of redirecting aliases of www.example.com and example.com to different servers.

Comment: thank you for your answer, there are no static URL in the theme. DNS is ok I check it. I can check DB of course...
but there is not a way to fix it on htaccess?

Comment: anyway your approach is interesting anyway... do you download a sql copy and than open with notepad++... and search and replace all records? than import the db?

Comment: @antony thats right, after replacing all occurrences (Ctrl+H), save (make a copy), then import into db